# How to detect whether a html text field is active or not?

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, input

I'm debugging an old jsp/javascript page, something strange happens : there is a bill search form on the page, a dozen or so input and select fields, it's a struts application, all other browsers work fine, except IE 10, the problem is when you load the page for the first time, everything is OK, but if you load that page again, the input fields freeze, when I mouse over and click in the fields, nothing happens, and it won't let me enter info, if you load that page a third time, it's OK again, but on the 4th time, it got frozen , so on and so forth. There is a "Clear" button on the page, when the form is frozen, you can click the button and it will call a javascript to clear cache, it will set some http sessions to null and redirect to that page, and the input fields will be active again.

Here are some lines of code :

```
    <form:form commandName="commandBean" 
     name="billingSearch">
      <div id="form-row">
      <div id="form-row-left">Carrier Name:</div>
      <div id="form-row-right">
      <form:select path="masterCompany" id="select_style">
      <form:options items="${commandBean.masterCompanyList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="masterCompanyName"/>
      </form:select>
      </div>
      </div>

       <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${!commandBean.agent}">
            <div id="form-row">
            <div id="form-row-left">Agency Name:</div>
            <div id="form-row-right">
            <form:select path="agency" id="select_style">
                <form:options items="${commandBean.agencyList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="agencyName"/>
            </form:select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </c:when>  
      </c:choose>
       <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${!commandBean.agent && !commandBean.mga && !commandBean.insured}">
            <div id="form-row">
            <div id="form-row-left">Agency Group:</div>
            <div id="form-row-right">
            <form:select path="agencyGroupId" id="select_style">
                <form:options items="${commandBean.agencyGroupList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="groupName"/>
            </form:select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </c:when>  
      </c:choose>
    ...
      <div id="form-row">
      <div id="form-row-left">Posting Date:</div>
      <div id="form-row-right">
      <div id="form-row-date">
      <div id="date-start-label">Start:</div>
      <div id="date-start-box">
        <form:input path="startDate"  size="10"></form:input>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                   new tcal ({
                       'formname': 'commandBean',
                       'controlname': 'startDate'
                   });
              </script>
      </div>
      <div id="date-end-label">End:</div>
      <div id="date-end-box">
        <form:input path="endDate"   size="10" ></form:input>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                   new tcal ({
                       'formname': 'commandBean',
                       'controlname': 'endDate'
                   });
              </script>
      </div>
      </div>  
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="form-submit-row">
      <div id="submit-left"><input name="submit" id="button_style" value="Search" type="submit" /></div>
      <div id="submit-right"><input onclick="clearBillingCache();"  name="reset" id="button_style" value="Clear" type="button" /></div>
      </div>
    </form:form>

...

function clearBillingCache(){
    window.location = "billingSearchClear.html"
}

...


        @RequestMapping(value = "/billingSearchClear.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String clearCache(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String returnVal = "redirect:/billingSearch.html";


            request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyCarrier", null);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyAgency", null);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyGroup", null);
    ...
            request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyStartDate", null);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyEndDate", null);

            return returnVal;
        }
```

What I've tried is add the following to the jsp page, so it calls onload on even number of clicks :

```
<%!
  int Counter=0;
%>
```

...
    <% 
    if (++Counter % 2 !=0)
    {

```
%>
 <body onload="clearBillingCache()">
 <%
}
else
{

%>
<body>
<%
}
System.out.println("  Counter = "+Counter);
%>
```

It refreshes on even clicks, but the fields are still frozen, until I click the "Clear" button.

And I printed out the session values, they are all null.

Has any one encountered this problem before ? How to let it load the form properly every time without clicking the clear form ?

Comment: "some lines of code" are always a bad question. Do you think these lines are the problem? If so, why? What have you tried and ruled out or confirmed that you can add as question details? If you're not sure whether these lines matter, then adding them at all is arbitrary and a thus a bad idea. If you can, clone this project, run the cloned copy, and start removing code until you've hit the minimal conditions for reproducing the bug. Then take it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the following change :

```
function delay(ms) {
    var cur_d = new Date();
    var cur_ticks = cur_d.getTime();
    var ms_passed = 0;
    while(ms_passed < ms) {
        var d = new Date();  // Possible memory leak?
        var ticks = d.getTime();
        ms_passed = ticks - cur_ticks;
        d = null;            // Prevent memory leak?
    }
}

<body onload="delay(300)">
```